# How to share project in Power BI to be able to put it in an iframe in HTML?

Tags: powerbi

How to share a project in Power BI to be able to put it in an iframe in HTML, but without requiring my users to have a Power BI account.

EDITADO:

I tried to follow the documentation, but the option to generate the public iframe does not appear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web

[Exemple window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD86g.png)

Comment: Have you tried following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web)?

Comment: Yes, but the public option does not appear.

Comment: If the publish option doesn't appear, that suggests one or more of the prerequisites has not been met.  Have you verified that you meet all of the prerequisites listed in the documentation linked in my comment above?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed Power BI content in a website whose users don't have Power BI accounts using "[Embed for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-customers)"

Note there's a security setting required to enable this style of embedding.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I followed the step by step, but apparently either I don't have the correct option, because the one I have to share, it generates an iframe with the link but it always asks me to login with an account, would there be some workspace configuration to do how does this work?